# Call function within function of AlpineJS

Tags: javascript

In the [AlpineJS docs](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#x-data) there's this example:

```
<div x-data="dropdown()">
    <button x-on:click="open()">Open</button>

    <div x-show="isOpen()" x-on:click.away="close()">
        // Dropdown
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function dropdown() {
        return {
            show: false,
            open() { this.show = true },
            close() { this.show = false },
            isOpen() { return this.show === true },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now what I would like to do is within that `<script>` have another function that calls `close()`, so something like:

```
function aNewFunction()
{
  close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dropdown().close
```

This will return close() if you want to call close then simply do something like this .

```
dropdown().close()
```